# What is tomcat7 exin doing?

Tags: tomcat7

When checking via `top` I see two processes for tomcat7:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                      
15163 tomcat7   20   0 2082064 317976  20816 S 55.4  7.8   0:54.49 java                                                                                         
  964 tomcat7   20   0  194332   5740   1404 S 18.9  0.1 284:09.36 exin
```

I wonder what exin is doing, why it consumes so much CPU power and why it is running for such a long time?

Searching for "tomcat7 exin" in Google revealed nothing. This is why I am asking here.

Comment: Probably sending spam, cryptocurrency mining, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. So this is not a required process which I killed. Need to investigate where this came from and how to prevent this. There is an Message Transfer Agent (MTA) called exim but ...

Comment: This indeed was a disaster since there were many more webapps which should have not been there. Harding Tomcat is a must!